# How can I restore the "auto" values for list-style-type in nested unordered lists?

Tags: css

By default, an unstyled set of nested `<ul>` lists looks like this (in Chrome, Firefox, and IE at least):

[image: Nested <ul> screenshot]

The top level has a `list-style-type` of `disc`, the next level is `circle`, and subsequent levels are `square`.

If I include a stylesheet that changes the `list-style-type` to `none`, is there a simple way to revert back to the "automatic bullet types" later in the document? (e.g., override with a subsequent CSS definition or JavaScript style change)

Basically, I'm looking for something like `list-style-type: auto;` (which is apparently not valid and has no effect):

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul { list-style-type: none; }
    ul { list-style-type: auto; } /* Does not work */
</style>
```

Setting the `list-style-type` back to `disc` changes every bullet in the list and I no longer see different bullets at different levels, so that doesn't work either.

Is the only way to accomplish this by explicitly defining styles for every level? e.g.:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul { list-style-type: disc; }
    ul ul { list-style-type: circle; }
    ul ul ul { list-style-type: square; }
</style>
```

Comment: Why don't you just give a class to your first `<ul>` or style it like `#somediv ul { display: none }`? In that case you don't have to redefine the others

Comment: You should not depend on the default appearance of things, since it changes from browser to browser. That's why designers use a **CSS reset**

Comment: I don't know if explicitly defining styles is the ONLY way, but it's the correct way.  You need not use the depth level to set the style.  you can also use named css classes. The css: `ul.flavor1 {list-style-type:circle;}` etc.  and then in html :  `<ul class='flavor1'>...</ul>`

Comment: I tried resetting the `list-style-type` using `list-style: ...`, but failed: http://jsfiddle.net/mjXsn/1/

Comment: The problem here is that it's not the spec that decides what list styles should be used as nesting levels go deeper - it's the browser that decides. The initial value for `list-style-type` is `disc`, and as you note, `auto` is not a valid value, nor are list styles automated in any way.

Comment: @biziclop: `list-style` is nothing more than a shorthand - if you omit the type then it'll just use `disc` (which as I mentioned in my comment is the initial value for `list-style-type`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use classes to write for something like:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }
.list_default { list-style-type: circle; }
```

and then on the ul you want to apply bullets to,

```
<ul class="list_default">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Also, please do take other posters advice when it comes to not using "auto" behaviors. There are so many proprietary extensions to the standard and manufacturer-defined defaults that will just make you pull your hair out later. Develop the good habit now of not depending on their sanity.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the only way to accomplish this by explicitly defining styles for every level?

Yep, using ul, it's the only way. Basically this exactly what chrome is doing.

If you still want to keep the chrome style starting at the second level, do not use ul for the first level! Use a div...

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a need for this (no nesting, but still preferred not implicitly setting roman vs. greek etc.) and used `inherit` with success. Naturally, effect will vary depending on what rules have been defined, but it worked in my case.