# Reset css list count and style when nested

Tags: css

I have following html code (simplified

```
<ol class="step">
<li><p>some content</p></li>
<li><p>some content</p>
    <ul class="bull">
   <li><p>some nested content</p></li>
   <li><p>some nested content</p></li>
   <li><p>some nested content</p></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><p>some content</p></li>
</ol>
```

and I created some css to make the list items  of the step class twice as big than normal font size. I've used the :before class to achieve this, and it all works fine until I have a nested list, ordered or unordered in my tree.

For some reason I'm not able to 'reset'the cascaded style, so any advice on how to do it correctly is welcome.

This is the css I have, if you use it you will notice the ul is also having big numbers, while actually I just want to have basic simple disc again.

```
ol.step{
    counter-reset: li;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-padding-start: 20px;
}

ol.step li:before{
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    font-size:  200%;
    font: Arial;
    position: absolute; 
    left: -20px;
    padding-top : 1px;
}

ol.step li{
display: block;
position: relative;
padding-left : 10px;
padding-top : 1px;
}

ul.bull {
    list-style-type: disc;
    counter-reset: li;
}
```

So what do I have to do to 'reset'my nested listings and let them behave nicely ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What does "reset" mean?  Do you want to start a style, and then stop it later in the page or deeper in the nest?  Can you use a different CSS class?

Comment: It should be stopped in the nesting, as the same sequence can be repeated a few times in the rest of the page. So listings within a list should not take anything from their parent

Comment: Is this Related ? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025047/how-can-i-restore-the-auto-values-with-for-list-style-type-in-nested-unordered  or you are talking about 'counter' restart ?

Comment: If you want to reset the counter on the OrderedList, see documentation here : 
  [1]: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/counter-reset
  [2]: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `li` styles to only apply to the `li` directly under the `ol.step` use the direct descendant CSS selector:

```
ol.step > li:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    font-size:  200%;
    font: Arial;
    position: absolute; 
    left: -20px;
    padding-top : 1px;
}

ol.step > li{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left : 10px;
    padding-top : 1px;
}
```